# How can I make if statement using the number of array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

findParent() function find array. There could be one array or more than one.

Now I want to make if statement depends on the number of array.

How can I make if statement using the number of array?

```
function findParent($order_id){

  ...
  $Q = $this->db->get('omc_order_item');
        if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
   ... 
   return $data; 

 }
```

I tried this, but it does not work.

```
function deleteitem($order_id){
    $childless = $this->MOrders->findParent($order_id);
    if ($childless<2){
        $data['childlessorder']= $this->MOrders->findParent($order_id);
...
```

It must be checking if $childless is less than 2.

How can I change it so that it will check the number of array is 1 (can be less than 2, doesn't it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean number of arrays then

```
if (count($childless) < 2)
```

From your example it looks like the `findParent()` function returns an array of arrays. To compare against the number of arrays contained within the resulting array you would use the `count(array())` function.

It returns the number of array items within the array passed as its argument.

For instance

```
echo count(
    array(
        0 => array(1,2),
        1 => array(3,4)
    )
);
```

would output 2

For documentation see the [php.net/count](http://php.net/count) page.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is the `count()` function. You pass it an array, and it returns the number of elements in the array. See: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 0):

$childless holds a lot of information, not just the number of rows, you need to extract the row count from $childless.  `if (count($childless) < 2 )` for example